# Play sound file into skype call

Tags: java, audio, skype

I am trying to play wav sound file into skype call. I am using javax.sound and first of all i listed all mixers in my system:

```
0,Primary Sound Driver
1,Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)
2,Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High Definition Audio Device)
3,Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High Definition Audio Device)
4,Primary Sound Capture Driver
5,Microphone (High Definition Aud
6,Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De
7,Java Sound Audio Engine
8,Port Speakers (High Definition Audio
9,Port Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De
10,Port Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De
11,Port Microphone (High Definition Aud
12,Port Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High De
```

Then I noticed that skype has S/PDIF in combobox for choosing the microphone. So I choosed it and used typical Clip to playback sound:

```
File file = new File("november.wav");
AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,  sound.getFormat());
Clip cl = (Clip) AudioSystem.getMixer(AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()[2]).getLine(info);
cl.open(sound);
cl.start();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

However this approach is for some reason unsuccessfull. When I choose typical mixer like 0 or 1 it plays back the sound perfectly but 2,3,6 doesnt work.

What is wrong with my approach? Is there any other way how to play back sound from disk so that skype accepts it? (couting out the option to stick microphone to speakers with duck tape).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Skype API to do this. Have a look at the [Skype4COM object](http://developer.skype.com/accessories).